# How to work on plugin and theme simultaneously in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have created a project using plugin skeleton.
Now how can I have a theme working simultaneously with the plugin?

I can create a theme bundle or add view under app

Sylius documentation says -
loading order (priority descending):

```
App templates:
<Theme>/views (NEW!)
app/Resources/views
Bundle templates:
<Theme>/<Bundle name>/views (NEW!)
app/Resources/<Bundle name>/views
<Bundle>/Resources/views
```

I can have a theme bundle registered and work simultaneously with plugin in `tests/app/AppKernel.php`

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your use-case. I'll try to identify some.

**1. Sharing plugin with others**

In case you want to share your plugin/bundle with others (open source e.g.), it would be best to have the plugin specific views inside your plugin. It allows other developers to override them inside their own theme or inside their `app/Resources` folder. In case they just like the views, they don't have to do anything besides loading the plugin.

**2. Sharing views with other projects**

Let's say you want to use your plugin in several own projects, but it might be that some views need to be adjusted. You will still put the default views inside the plugin as mentioned above, but if some need slight adjustments in that project or in some projects, you override them inside that theme. A theme can also be loaded from a repository, therefore making it possible for you to open-source the theme or use it internally in multiple projects.

**3. No sharing**

In this case I think it's up to your own preference where you place them. Myself I would still save them with the plugin and override them in a theme. In case my very specific app still needs to behave differently, the `app/Resources` is a last resort. Placing views inside the plugin or inside the theme will allow you to (in case you place them inside a repository) easily also loading them in another project. Besides that, you share responsibilities by grouping functionality together.

*Recap*

Basically it depends on your needs, but in case you want to share your plugin and/or theme with others, definitely place the files inside the plugin first, and any adjustments inside the theme.

Is it only for internal use? In that case it's up to your preference, but I would still keep in mind maintainability and reusability, therefore placing them together with the part that introduced the accompanying functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on use cases. Can you tell me how can I override stylus shop layouts in my plugin, without having a themebundle?

Comment: Let's say you want to override the template in 'vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/views/Product/_box.html.twig', you make a file in '<plugin>/Resources/SyliusShopBundle/views/Product/_box.html.twig' and have your own version of it in there. More info here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc. A plugin is basically a bundle, therefore sharing the same concepts.

Comment: I can override templates successfully, unfortunately, all shop bundle routes have disappeared, once I added `getParent()` function to return `SyliusShopBundle` in bundle class. Can you give me a full-fledged example of a working plugin with overridden template configuration?

Comment: That feels to me like an unrelated issue. Not sure where you are adding this `getParent()`? In which file?